# Can't install flickr api on windows anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, flickr

I want to install flickr api from anaconda prompt according to it's installation but i get 404 error while installation . First i login into anaconda then do this instruction :

anaconda login

pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple flickrapi

Comment: Did you mean `https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple/flickr-api/`?

Comment: i use this doc : https://anaconda.org/pypi/flickrapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a problem with a dependency using `pip install -i https://pypi.anaconda.org/pypi/simple flickrapi`. It works for me using easy_install. `easy_install flickrapi`, then `easy_install -U flickrapi` to update whenever you want to update to the latest version. I got this information from [here](https://stuvel.eu/flickrapi)
.

Comment: I did this and installed well but when i want import flickr , still no module name error

Comment: Did you `import flickr` or `import flickrapi`?

Comment: sorry but some of methods i want to use in flickr not flickrapi !!

Comment: Can you give me an example of what is not available?